# What happened with a recent question about a 6V motor and a 5V LDO regulator? Apparently user was removed along with all content

Tags: discussion, moderation

There was a question about powering a 6V motor and also a 5V circuit that needed a regulator. There were several answers explaining why the 7805 type regulators have too high dropout voltage and are unsuitable. I provided an answer with a simple LDO regulator that could be built and used. I saw that my reputation dropped by 5 points because the user and all content were removed. I am curious as to why this was done.

Comment: Hi, Are you asking why the user was removed? In that case, do you realise it wasn't necessarily a mod action? Or are you asking why your reputation score dropped? (FYI it's difficult for user being removed to cause a drop of exactly 5 points. I can think of only 1 very unlikely way. However I can see a drop of 10 points in your rep when a user was recently removed.) AFAIK your content was not removed; I found your answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/648409/101852) so I'm confused by that part of your question, which seems to suggest otherwise. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: Regarding "reputation dropped by 5 points", see [Recent achievement count not matching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263364/recent-achievement-count-not-matching).  It is always best to post a screenshot for what you see.

Comment: It was just that I could not find the Q&A, and thought it had been totally removed. I suppose I need to find a better way to find threads. I have opted to "follow" it so that should make it easier to find in the future. I may have had a concurrent 10 point drop and 5 point increase. Thanks. BTW, what are the criteria for having a member removed?

Comment: @PStechPaul You can retrieve your latest [answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/316329/pstechpaul?tab=answers&sort=newest) and [questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/316329/pstechpaul?tab=questions&sort=newest) from your [account](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/316329/pstechpaul) page. You don't need to follow your own posts to retrieve them.